# How to change #include with #define in c?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to change the #include syntax? Here's an example of I am trying to reach out with this.

```
#define begin {
#define end }
#define import #include
import <stdio.h>


int main() begin
 return 0;
end
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213156/discussion-on-question-by-pedroravel-how-to-change-include-with-define-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Not really. At least not in a way that would fill any practical meaning.

First, the preprocessor is run and it till change "import" to "#include", and then it gives the output to the compiler. But the compiler does not understand preprocessor directives. Also, the C language does not have any functionality to include files. That's supposed to be handled by the preprocessor.

So one thing that CAN be done, although it's not something you should ever do in production code is to run the preprocessor twice. It's very likely that this approach will yield bugs that are tricky to find.

```
$ cat a.c
#define begin {
#define end }
#define import #include 
import <stdio.h>
int main() begin
 return 0;
end

$ gcc -E a.c > b.c
$ cat b.c 
# 1 "a.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "a.c"



#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
 return 0;
}

$ gcc b.c
$
```

You could simplify the above to one command like this:

```
gcc -E a.c | gcc -xc -
```

(The final dash is important)

Comment: @AndrejHatzi One could only speculate. I'd assume it's partially because I used the gold hammer to reopen the question before answering, and partially because this is code that it should not ever be used in production code.

Comment: We are here to answer questions not to judge anyone.

Comment: @AndrejHatzi Well, people are free to vote. And the describing text above the dv button is "this answer is not useful", and I completely understand if people don't find this useful :)

Comment: It is not correct to say “But the compiler does not understand preprocessor directives” or “Also, the C language does not have any functionality to include files”. Preprocessing is part of the C language. It is defined in clause 6.10 of the standard. It is the fourth of eight phases of translating a C program. In common modern compilers, it is integrated into the compiler. In spite of its name and history, preprocessing may not be completed before other parts of compilation. For example, in Clang, compiling the two lines `a b c` / `#error` produces an error message about the first line first.

Answer (score 0):

Per C 2018 6.10.3.4 3, after a macro has been substituted:

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one,…

Thus, defining a macro to expand to `#include` will not result in an `#include` directive being processed.